# Update QUERY_STRING without page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I currently have this code snippet in a CGI script:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode)  {
        case 37:
            document.location = "?direction=West";
            break;
        case 38:
            document.location = "?direction=North";
            break;
        case 39:
            document.location = "?direction=East";
            break;
        case 40:
            document.location = "?direction=South";
            break;
    }
};
```

That will update the `QUERY_STRING` and then reload the page.
Can this be done without constantly reloading after every key stroke?
JSON? jQuery?

I've tried fiddling with `url.replace()` and `history.pushState()`.. no luck..

Comment: This question is **way** too broad. A good direction would be start reading about jQuery and AJAX.

Comment: This code will not reload after every keystroke. If that happens, there must be some other code as well. Also, `history.pushState()` should allow you to change the url without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `window.history.pushState('page1', 'Title', 'page1?direction=West');`
for this.
for more infomation adn help check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Comment: Ok, that seems to update the link correctly, but how do I submit the form? For the cgi to process it?